# Kendo UI MVC DropDownList Focus For Filtering

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, telerik-mvc

I am using MVC Razor and Telerik Kendo MVC. I have a dropdownlst that I would like to automatically set focus on so that the user can immediately begin typing and filtering for the desired value. The ddl is:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("ddlLocations")
    .Filter("contains")
    .BindTo(Model.Locations)
    .DataTextField("Text")
    .DataValueField("Value")
    .Events(events => events.Change("onChange"))
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
    .Value(Model.Exception.LocationIDCouponTypeStatus)
)
```

I have a similar project in ASP.NET WebForms and what I did in Javascript is:

```
 var comboBox = $find("<%=ddl.ClientID %>");
 comboBox._inputDomElement.select();
```

This focused on the part of the control that tells it to start filtering when the user begins to type. It doesn't seem to be translating to the MVC version.

```
var comboBox = $("#ddlLocations").data("kendoDropDownList");
comboBox._inputDomElement.select();
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open dropdownlist first:

```
.Events(p => p.DataBound("function(e){ this.open(); this.filterInput.focus(); }"))
```

**Alternatives:**

```
$(function(){
    var dd = $("#ddlLocations").data("kendoDropDownList");
    dd.open();
    dd.filterInput.focus();
});
```

or

```
.Events(p => p.DataBound("function(e){ setTimeout(function(){ this.open(); this.filterInput.focus(); }, 500); }"))
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do it without opening the list first? Only because I have a variable image above the ddl that sometimes is a little delayed in loading and when it does depending on its size it moves the controls down on the screen. So what ends up happening is the opened list gets rendered at a certain point on the page, and then the image loads and pushes everything down and the opened list is still in its original spot. Also I don't necessarily want to open the list, they may or may not want to start typing they might just tab off to the next field. Your solution technically works though.

Comment: @Cef well the search input is located inside dropdown popup, so you need to open it first, but you can try setTimeout for delayed opening, or call it inside document ready event:`$(function(){ .... })` or `success` callback if it is ajax request

Comment: Yes I am noticing that it is different than the AJAX control. I may try using the combobox see if it meets my needs. Thanks for the assist!

Answer (score 0):

Much easier than that, Kendo already has a focus() function, just do comboBox.focus()

Comment: Although this does put focus the control it does not allow you to start typing without further input from the mouse.